# Javascript variable scope in MVC _Layout page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have  in MVC scripts, script that I put in my shared _Layout, this mean the JavaScript is available to all the views. My question is if I declare a variable in this JavaScript file lets say: var x=true;  and I change it in others view it will be up dated all over the application? I mean the script is "alive" in all my MVC application?

Comment: Try it! I presume as long as the variable has global scope, i.e it's not declared within a function etc. then the variable will be accessible everywhere your JS file is referenced

Comment: I know it is accessible but my question is maybe it will return to its initial state in some point...

Comment: No, if they all have access to the same variable, then acting on that variable, i.e changing it from `True` to `False` will be the same everywhere, they don't all see a different instance of the variable.